# How to implement timeout in react native while react native application is in foreground and also if application is in background?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am stuck with a react native problem. I want to setState after a long time say 20minutes. For that i tried with setTimeout function but this is giving me waring - ***"Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground."***

> setTimeout(() => {
> this.setState({
> showButton:true,
> })   }, 1200000);

How to solve this problem ? Is there any way to set long period timeout in react native?
Anyone Please help me to solve this problem. Thank You all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) seems to be a package created for exactly this

> "You can use the setInterval and setTimeout functions. This API is identical to that of react-native and can be used to quickly replace existing timers with background timers."